# Excel multiple conditional check including contains

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Having trouble figuring out how to piece this together, not to mention coming up with a descriptive title for this question.

Psuedocode of what I'm trying to do in a cell is:

```
if ((A1 == 1 && B1.contains("abc")) || (A1 == 2 && B1.contains("def") || (A1 == 3 && B1.contains("ghi"))
then write("ok")
else write("not ok")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be case-sensitive. For case-insensitive, use `SEARCH` instead of `FIND`.

```
=IF(OR(AND(A1=1,IFERROR(FIND("abc",B1)>0,FALSE)),AND(A1=2,IFERROR(FIND("def",B1)>0,FALSE)),AND(A1=3,IFERROR(FIND("ghi",B1)>0,FALSE))),"ok","not ok")
```

Or

```
=IF(IFERROR(FIND(INDEX({"abc","def","ghi"},$A$1),$B$1),FALSE),"ok","not ok")
```

Comment: Something tells me the `1,2,3` are simplifications of the actual inputs.  If not then the second is a good formula.

Comment: @ScottCraner In my real case, the inputs happen to actually be 1 through 6, but your point is spot on.

Comment: I'm going to accept this because I was able to take the first sample and expand it out as I needed. I admire you guys who can think in a single line of code. I had to add line breaks and spacing to understand what the pieces were.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
=IF(IFERROR(MATCH(A1,{1,2,3},0)=MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"abc","def","ghi"},B1)),0),FALSE),"OK","NOT OK")
```

As an array formula, which must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

If your values in Column A are actually numeric 1,2,3,... then you can simplify the formula to:

```
=IF(IFERROR(A1=MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"abc","def","ghi"},B1)),0),FALSE),"OK","NOT OK")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's the outline:

```
=IF(OR(AND({conditions}),AND({conditions}),AND({conditions})),"OK","NOT OK")
```

Does cell contain text?
https://exceljet.net/formula/cell-contains-specific-text